# How does addition look like at the opcode level in Solidity v0.8 and above?

Tags: opcode, overflow, math, solidity-0.8.x

In Solidity v0.7 and below, addition was a simple opcode:

```
ADD
```

Which cost 3 gas units and didn't handle overflows, silently returning the overflown value.

But Solidity v0.8 [made](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.2/080-breaking-changes.html) addition overflow-safe. How does the sequence of opcodes look like today?